# Insert a Sparql Query Into Ontotext GraphDB

Tags: sparql, semantics, graphdb

I am using Ontotext GraphDB to store semantic data.

GraphDB allows to store/save sparql queries which are exposed as web services.
However I want to store/save sparql queries through HTTP POST request. Below is my query and name of the query will be `Query-1`:

```
let $Query := fn:concat('PREFIX dc: <http://insert/>
                         INSERT DATA
                         {
                             dc:a@gmail.com dc:played dc:1234 .
                         }
                       ')
let $EncodeUri  := fn:encode-for-uri($Query)
```

Can anyone help me to write HTTP-POST request command to save this query in GraphDB? I want to use `xdmp:http-post()` only.

To get the query result I have used `xdmp:http-get('http://localhost:8080//rest/sparql/saved-queries/Query-2')` which works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute a POST request to store queries.
Following example is using curl:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/rest/sparql/saved-queries\
 -H 'Content-Type:application/json'\
 -d '{
     "body": "select * { ?s ?p ?o }",
     "name": "Query-2"
 }'
```

You can also find more details about the REST API using GraphDB Workbench (Admin -> REST API Documentation)

Comment: Thanks Venelin. I have used curl but I want to call through `marklogic`, so I can use only `xdmp:http-post()` .

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to make and ingest a Sparql Query through MarkLogic. You may use following code to implement it:

```
import module namespace  sem    = "http://marklogic.com/semantics"          at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

let $Query := 'select * { ?s ?p ?o }'
let $QueryName := 'abcdef'
let $EncodesQuery  := fn:encode-for-uri($Query)
let $QData := fn:concat('{
                          "body": "',$Query,'",
                          "name": "',$QueryName,'"
                        }')
return
  xdmp:http-post(concat('http://localhost:9080/rest/sparql/saved-queries'),
              <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
                <data>{$QData}</data>
                <headers>
                  <content-type>application/json</content-type>
                </headers>
              </options>
              )
```

Comment: Thanks Navin, it helped